# Postgres before insert trigger using sequence from another table

Tags: postgresql, triggers, sql-insert

Using Postgres, what I would like to achieve is to be able to have many different instrument types, with corresponding `[TYPE].instrument` tables, which all have a unique ID in the table, but also reference a unique ID in the `instrument.master` table. I have the following:

```
create schema instrument

CREATE TABLE instrument.type (
    id smallserial NOT NULL,
    name text not null,
    code text not null,
    CONSTRAINT pk_instrument_type PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE instrument.type ADD CONSTRAINT unq_instrument_type_code UNIQUE(code);
ALTER TABLE instrument.type ADD CONSTRAINT unq_instrument_type_name UNIQUE(name);

insert into instrument.type (name, code) values ('futures', 'f');

CREATE TABLE instrument.master (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    type smallint not null references instrument.type (id),
    timestamp timestamp with time zone not null,
    CONSTRAINT pk_instrument_master PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE futures.definition (
    id smallserial NOT NULL,
    code text not null,
    CONSTRAINT pk_futures_definition PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE futures.definition ADD CONSTRAINT unq_futures_definition_code UNIQUE(code);

insert into futures.definition (code) values ('ED');

CREATE TABLE futures.instrument (
    id smallserial NOT NULL,
    master serial not null references instrument.master (id),
    definition smallint not null references futures.definition (id),
    month smallint not null,
    year smallint not null,
    CONSTRAINT pk_futures_instrument PRIMARY KEY (id),
    check (month >= 1),
    check (month <= 12),
    check (year >= 1900)
);

ALTER TABLE futures.instrument ADD CONSTRAINT unq_futures_instrument UNIQUE(definition, month, year);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_master_futures()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    insert into instrument.master (type, timestamp)
    select id, current_timestamp from instrument.type where code = 'f';
    NEW.master := currval('instrument.master_id_seq');

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;

create trigger trg_futures_instrument before insert on futures.instrument
for each row
execute procedure trigger_master_futures();
```

I then test with:

```
insert into futures.instrument (definition, month, year)
select id, 3, 2015 from futures.definition where code = 'ED';
```

Everything works almost as I would like it to. The only issue is that somehow, `instrument.master.id` ends up being one more than `futures.instrument.master`. I am not sure what I need to do to achieve the behavior I want, which is that whenever an entry is inserted into `futures.instrument`, an entry should be inserted into `instrument.master`, and the `id` entry of the latter should be inserted into the `master` entry of the former. I actually think it should have failed since the foreign key relationship is violated somehow.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, everything was correct. The issue was that in `futures.instrument`, the type of the master column is `serial`, and it should have been `int`.